# Cannot subscript a value of type - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and am trying to write an application to parse json from a webpage. However I'm getting the error 
"Cannot subscript a value of type '[Dictionary]'"

How can I fix this? It occurs multiple times. Following is my code. Thanks!

```
func grabData(results: [Dictionary<String, Any?>]){
    guard let resultList = results as? [Dictionary<String, Any?>] else { return }
        for iResult in resultList {
            var tempResult = SearchResult()
            tempResult.studentId = self.getInt(dict: [iResult], string: "StudentId")
            tempResult.LastName = self.getString(dict: [iResult], string: "LastName")
            tempResult.FirstName = self.getString(dict: [iResult], string: "FirstName")
            tempResult.Major = self.getString(dict: [iResult], string: "Major")
            tempResult.Year = self.getString(dict: [iResult], string: "Year")
            tempResult.GPA = self.getDouble(dict: [iResult], string: "GPA")
            self.results.append(tempResult)
        }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func getString(dict: [Dictionary<String, Any?>], string: String) -> String? {
    if let result = dict[Dictionary<String, Any?>] as? String {
        return result
    }
    return nil
}

func getInt(dict: [Dictionary<String, Any?>], string: String) -> Int? {
    if let result = dict[string] as? Int {
        return result
    }
    return nil
}

func getDouble(dict: [Dictionary<String, Any?>], string: String) -> Double? {
    if let result = dict[string] as? Double {
        return result
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a library for parsing JSON, this would make your life pretty easy ... I wrote a library that is available at https://github.com/borchero/WebParsing.

Comment: Avoid declaring optional value types in Swift dictionaries. They are not very meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SearchResult.swift**

```
struct SearchResult {
    let studentID: Int
    let lastName: String
    let firstName: String
    let major: String
    let year: String
    let gpa: Double

    init?(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
        guard let studentID = json["StudentID"] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let lastName = json["LastName"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let firstName = json["FirstName"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let major = json["Major"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let year = json["Year"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let gpa = json["GPA"] as? Double else {
            return nil
        }

        self.studentID = studentID
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.major = major
        self.year = year
        self.gpa = gpa
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
func grabData(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
    guard let searchResult = SearchResult(json) else {
        return
    }

    self.results.append(searchResult)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This post was helpful to me when I designing my model to interact with a REST API: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

The structure of your JSON also makes a difference.

For example:

```
[
    {
        "StudentID": 12345,
        "LastName": "Smith"
    }
]
```

Would be represented as `[[String:AnyObject]]` (an array of String and AnyObject combinations)

If you have this, then you need to loop through and then parse each element individually.

Comment: This was very helpful. But now I'm getting an error on this line... What do I need to change the "String:AnyObject" to? This is the line =>
                "self.grabData(json: json as [String:AnyObject])"

Comment: I created a new post for it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663503/cant-convert-value-of-type-swift Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try changing your

```
[Dictionary<String, Any?>]
```

to

```
[String: Any]
```

And I would recommend you to look at this article made by 
Apple. (It should help you with understanding what is wrong):

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're passing in an array of dictionaries:

```
dict: [Dictionary<String, Any?>]
```

Which should instead be:

```
dict: Dictionary<String, Any?>
```

If you're then going to subsequently use something like:

```
if let result = dict[string] as? Int
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to get rid of the errors however now my application isn't parsing correctly as I'm not getting any data to print. I'm new to stackoverflow, do I post the rest of my code here in this comment or main post?

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  If this helped solve your problem I'd appreciate if you accepted the answer.  Then I would recommend trying to evaluate your new problem as much as possible and then ask a new detailed question in another post with relevant code related to that problem.