# Can't convert value of type - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having an issue with parsing in Swift where it says I can't convert value of type [Dictionary] to type [String:AnyObject]
This is the line that causes the error

```
self.grabData(json: json as [String : AnyObject])
```

This is the whole code. Thanks!

```
 func jsonParser() {
    let urlPath = "http://csmadison.dhcp.bsu.edu/~vjtanksale/cs320/selectstudents.php"
    guard let endpoint = URL(string: urlPath) else {
        print("Error creating endpoint")
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: endpoint)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [Dictionary<String, Any?>] else {
                print("No idea")
                return
            }
            print(json)
            self.grabData(json: json as [String : AnyObject])   // This is where I get the error
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        }.resume()
}

func grabData(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
    guard let searchResult = SearchResult(json: json) else {
        return
    }

    self.results.append(searchResult)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is because you are trying to convert a `[[String:Any?]]` to `[String:AnyObject]`.

Try changing

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [Dictionary<String, Any?>]
```

to

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Then you need to loop through each object of your JSON result:

```
for result in json {
    if let student = SearchResult(json: result) {
        self.results.append(student)
    }
}

self.grabData()
```

Also, change your grabData function to the code below, or combine the reloading of the table view with your jsonParser function.

```
func grabData() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

So all together it would like:

```
func jsonParser() {
    let urlPath = "http://csmadison.dhcp.bsu.edu/~vjtanksale/cs320/selectstudents.php"
    guard let endpoint = URL(string: urlPath) else {
        print("Error creating endpoint")
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: endpoint)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] else {
                print("No idea")
                return
            }
            print(json)

            for result in json {
                if let student = SearchResult(json: result) {
                    self.results.append(student)
                }
            }
            self.grabData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        }.resume()
}

func grabData() {    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

For reference here is **SearchResult.swift**

```
struct SearchResult {
    let studentID: Int?
    let lastName: String?
    let firstName: String?
    let major: String?
    let year: String?
    let gpa: Double?

    init(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
        if let studentID = json["StudentID"] as? Int {
            self.studentID = studentID
        } else {
            self.studentID = nil
        }

        if let lastName = json["LastName"] as? String {
            self.lastName = lastName
        } else {
            self.lastName = nil
        }

        if let firstName = json["FirstName"] as? String {
            self.firstName = firstName
        } else {
            self.firstName = nil
        }

        if let major = json["Major"] as? String {
            self.major = major
        } else {
            self.major = nil
        }

        if let year = json["Year"] as? String {
            self.year = year
        } else {
            self.year = nil
        }

        if let gpa = json["GPA"] as? Double {
            self.gpa = gpa
        } else {
            self.gpa = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. However my results dictionary is empty after this. Only json has data in it.

Comment: Is `result` empty when looping? or is your `self.results` empty?

Comment: Both of them are empty. I believe that the for result in json loop isnt appending it.

Comment: Furthermore, in that loop it gets data in "for result in json" but "if let student..." doesnt return any data.

Comment: Ok, then the issue must be in SearchResult. Are all of the fields present in the JSON result? Does every student have a StudentID, LastName, FirstName, Major, Year and GPA? If even one of these are not present, then the SearchResult will return nil.

Comment: Yeah some of them don't have values present. How can I make it so it doesn't return nil but return empty?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Specifically the SearchResult struct. If the specified key is not in the JSON result, or it cannot be converted to the appropriate type, then the value will be set to nil. You could also set the properties to some default value.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you should get an Array of Dictionaries.
try this line:

```
self.grabData(json: json as [[String : AnyObject]])
```